# Android application crashing when launched with rejection of UnityPlayscapeActivityLifecycle class

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, playscape

Using Unity 4.5.4f1 and Playscape SDK version 1.14, building for android target, I am getting a crash when launching the application on testing target HTC-One M9 (which ran our application fine using the previous version of the SDK).
The one error which seems relevant from the Device Monitor log is this:

> 09-07 17:46:51.051: E/art(15746): Rejecting class
>   com.playscape.publishingkit.UnityPlayscapeActivityLifeCycle that
>   attempts to sub-class erroneous class
>   com.playscape.publishingkit.PlayscapeActivityLifeCycle in
>   /data/app/com.playscape.zombie_snipe1-2/base.apk

I do not understand the error so I am wondering what it means, (beyond a class trying something the operating system does not approve of), or even better, how to resolve the issue. I have failed to find the class by searching the text-indexed directories of the SDK.

Best Regards
Jakob
Three Gates

Comment: Are you sure you use 1.14? It was just released on Sep 10th. Can you verify that indeed you are using 1.14?